# How to build my sql query by queryBuilder in Yii2?

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii2, query-builder

My solution:

```
$author_id = 25;
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT author_id AS label
          FROM users
         WHERE author_id ::text LIKE '%:term%' AND role = 'Editor'";
$query = Users::findbysql($sql, [ ':term' => $author_id ] )->all();
```

The problem is the label alias, which then fails with: `author_id ::text LIKE '%:term%'`

Answer (score 0):

try manage the param for like string using concat

```
    $author_id = 25;
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT author_id AS label
              FROM users
             WHERE author_id ::text LIKE concat('%', :term,'%') AND role = 'Editor'";
    $query = Users::findbysql($sql, [ ':term' => $author_id ] )->all();
```

And if you have not a field `label` in your model then in you Users Class  add pubblic  var `$label`

```
    class Users extends  \yii\db\ActiveRecord
    {

        public $lable;

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
            ....
```

Comment: ok, that helped but now another error:
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "label" does not exist

Comment: @Honorum   .. this is strange because  label si an alias  .and don't should raise d this error  ..  please update your questuion and add the new code you are really using

Comment: please add label as a `public` field in `Users` model

Comment: answer  updated ..  with the code for class Users too.. as suggeted  bu @RaihanUddin

Answer (score 0):

SQL `concat()` concatenates strings.

You should use `':term'` to provide a string.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to use a query builder, it should be like:

```
$author_id = 25;
$users = Users::find()
    ->select(['label' => 'author_id'])
    ->distinct()
    ->andWhere(['ilike', new Expression('"author_id"::text'), $author_id])
    ->andWhere(['role' => 'Editor'])
    ->all();
```

And note the @ScaisEdge answer about adding `label` property to the `Users` ActiveRecord class. All table column values are available through magic methods due to schema inspecting. Key names that are not presented in schema but declared in query result, you should define as public properties or private/protected with `set<KeyName>()` methods in the target ActiveRecord class.

The other way is to use the array result of the query without creating objects. It reaches by adding `->asArray()` to the calls chain before the `->all()` method execution.